# Proving that any linear operator from a Banach space into itself such that $A^7 = A$ has closed range

Tags: functional-analysis

As the title says, i am looking for some hints/pointers to prove that any continuous linear operator $A$ from a Banach space $X$ to itself that satisfies $A^7 = A$ has closed range. I am thinking of using the closed image theorem but i can't seem to find the  way.

The hypothesis $A^7 = A$ confuses me and i don't really know how to use it.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosFoivos I guess  you meant:  If $Ax_n\to y$ then $Ax_n=A^7x_n\to A^6y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of $A$ is equal to the kernel of $A^6 - 1$ (this follows easily from $A^7 = A$), hence it is closed.

PS: Much more generally, if $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $A:X \to X$ is a continuous map such that $A^n =A$ for some $n > 1$, then the image of $A$ is closed, since it is the [equalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_%28mathematics%29#In_category_theory?wprov=sfla1) of the continuous maps $A^{n-1},1 : X \to X$.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering $Ran A \subset Ker(A^6 - I)$ but i was not sure about the opposite inclusion

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes pretty much! Thank you. Now i am trying to decide if such an image can be part of a decomposition of X. (Something like $X = Ran A \otimes B$). 
I am thinking that generally this is false but the decomposition v = v - Av + Av puts some doubts on this.

Comment: Well, $A^6$ is idempotent, hence $X = \mathrm{im}(A^6) \oplus \ker(A^6)$, and $\mathrm{im}(A^6) = \mathrm{im}(A)$.

Comment: I actualy proved it the same way. It's strange tho. I am doing exercises on functional analysis but i have yet to use any of the results i studied. (Like H-B theorem or open map theorem)

Comment: If you think the answer is complete, you can accept it by the way.